# Constraint logic programming with sets in Prolog

Tags: prolog, set, constraint-programming, logic-programming

The clpfd is a constraint programming library for integers in SWI Prolog. Is there a similar library for sets? If not, do you know of any articles useful to implement such library?

Is it doable at all? I'm looking for any kind of input really, as my googlings have returned nothing of interest.

Edit:
Using quotes when searching gives much better results (doh!). Well... happy to receive feedback anyway.

Edit:
There is a library included B-Prolog (clpset) that does precisely this.

Comment: I have the paper "Notes on Implementing Sets in Prolog" by Toshinori Munakata (Communications of the ACM, March 1992, Vol.35, No.3) right in front of me. It's still [paywalled at the ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=131295.131300), sadly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can find CLP(Set) in SICTUS Prolog or [B-Prolog](http://www.probp.com/manual/node115.html). Since [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/) inherits the virtual machine of of B-Prolog, I think you could as well experiment such constraints with an *imperative*, new language.

Comment: Thanks for the "picat" reference. I have never hever heard of that language before.